# JavaScript - Filter a array by iterating on another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iteration

The first object{array}, the one i want to filter :

```
const object1 = {
  "count" : 2,
  "result" : [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ]
}
```

The second array :

```
const array2 = [{
 "id": 1,
 "id": 44
}]
```

I want to filter the first array `object1.result` (or create a new array apart from it) if `object.result[i].id` is equal to `array2[i].id` , an reduce the number of array count `object1.count` based on the number of filter element.

in the example above I should have a new object :

```
theNewObject = {
  "count" : 1,
  "result" : [
  { "id": 2 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your objects look like that? You can't have duplicate properties.

Comment: Wow ... And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I modified it @MichałPerłakowski

Comment: @Exception_al A combination of `map` and `filter`

Comment: The question's body still has invalid JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) an collect all `id` for filtering.

```js
var object = { count : 2, result : [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] },
    array = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 44 }],
    ids = new Set(array.map(({ id }) => id));
    
object.result = object.result.filter(({ id }) => ids.has(id));
object.count = object.result.length;

console.log(object);
```

An approach which counts down the count.

```js
var object = { count : 2, result : [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] },
    array = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 44 }],
    ids = new Set(array.map(({ id }) => id));

object.result = object.result.filter(({ id }) => ids.has(id) || !object.count--);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: can one calculate the `count` otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```js
const object1 = {
  count: 2,
  result: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
  ],
};

const array2 = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 4 },
];

const filteredResult = object1.result.filter(({ id }) => !array2.find(x => x.id === id));
const object3 = {
  count: filteredResult.length,
  result: filteredResult,
};
console.log(object3);
```

The `{ id }` syntax is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

You can also use `reduce()`:

```js
const object1 = {
  count: 2,
  result: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
  ],
};

const array2 = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 4 },
];

const object3 = object1.result.reduce(
  ({ count, result }, { id }) => array2.find(x => x.id === id)
    ? ({ count, result })
    : ({ count: count + 1, result: result.concat([{ id }]) }),
  { count: 0, result: [] },
);

console.log(object3);
```

Comment: that's what I need, no way to calculate the `count` otherwise? with reduce for example?